# Getting information from 2 mysql tables at once

Tags: mysql

So I'm new to MYSQL and am confronted with a major problem (at least for me)
I've got 2 tables cwd_user and cwd_membership
I want to get all users from my database who have not logged in since august 31st 2020 AND who are part of a specific group.

The first query I came up with is this:

```
SELECT u.user_name as "Username"
     , u.display_name as "Full Name"
     , to_timestamp(CAST(a.attribute_value as bigint)/1000) as "Last Login" 
  FROM cwd_user u
  LEFT 
  JOIN cwd_user_attributes a 
    ON u.id = a.user_id 
   AND attribute_name = 'login.lastLoginMillis' 
 WHERE a.attribute_value >= '1598824800000' 
    OR a.attribute_value IS NULL
 ORDER 
    BY a.attribute_value;
```

How can I also get information from the second table at the same time?

The tables look like this:

cwd_membership:

```
id   |  parent_name   |   child_name
1    | finance        | tomi
2    | hr             | stro
3    | hr             | sujo
```

cwd_user:

```
id   |  user_name    | display_name |I dunno which fields the query I found only gets the "Last Login" from
1     | tomi          | Todd Miller  |?
2     | stro          | Steve Rogers |?
3     | sujo          | Susan Jones  |?
```

The query gives me the username, eg. tomi and stro their full name and the last time they logged in like this:

```
Username | Full Name   | Last Login
tomi     | Tdd Miller  | July 1st 2020
stro     | Steve Rogers| June 1st 2020
sujo     | Susan Jones | April 1st
```

What I want this to display though, is ONLY those who belong to the group "hr" and no others.

I hope I could express my point and someone can help me.

Comment: Note that '1598824800000' is a string. That may or may not be what you want.

Comment: `to_timestamp()` is not a thing in MySQL. Are you sure that's the database that you are running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In much the same way as you joined `cwd_attributes` in your query, you can also join in `cwd_membership` and then check to see if the joined data meets your criteria.

Your query with an additional `JOIN`:

```
SELECT u.user_name as "Username"
     , u.display_name as "Full Name"
     , to_timestamp(CAST(a.attribute_value as bigint)/1000) as "Last Login" 
  FROM cwd_user u
  INNER JOIN cwd_membership m
    ON m.child_name=u.user_name
    AND m.parent_name='hr'
  LEFT JOIN cwd_user_attributes a 
    ON u.id = a.user_id
    AND attribute_name = 'login.lastLoginMillis' 
 WHERE
    a.attribute_value >= '1598824800000' OR a.attribute_value IS NULL
 ORDER 
    BY a.attribute_value;
```